# How to use u-boot verified boot with multiple keys for signature verification?

Tags: security, embedded-linux, u-boot

I'm trying to use u-boot verified boot to support my use case. Ideally, I want to have two set of kernel, ramdisk, dtb 1). for production use only, 2). for development scenario.

I generated two keys with corresponding `public key` - `dev.key`, `dev.crt`, `prod.key`, `prod.crt`.

For testing I created a FIT source file as following, but the u-boot.dtb generated only put production key in the binary, there is no sign of development key (the structure is there but it is missing `rsa,r-squared` and `rsa,modulus`). Any idea hwo to do this correctly? thank you!

```
/dts-v1/;
/ {
    description = "fitImage for Tegra TX2";
    #address-cells = <1>;
    images {
        kernel-1 {
            description = "Linux kernel";
            data = /incbin/("Image");
            ...
            hash-1 {
                algo = "sha256";
            };
        };
        fdt-1 {
            description = "DTB for Tegra TX2";
            data = /incbin/("tegra186-base.dtb");
            ...
            hash-1 {
                algo = "sha256";
            };
        };
        ramdisk-1 {
            description = "Ramdisk Image for Tegra TX2";
            data = /incbin/("initrd");
            ...
            hash-1 {
                algo = "sha256";
            };
        };
    };
    configurations {
        default = "conf-1";
        conf-1 {
            description = "Production build";
            kernel = "kernel-1";
            fdt = "fdt-1";
            ramdisk = "ramdisk-1";
            signature-1 {
                algo = "sha256,rsa2048";
                key-name-hint = "prod";
                sign-images = "kernel", "fdt", "ramdisk";
            };
        };
        conf-2 {
            description = "Development build";
            kernel = "kernel-1";
            fdt = "fdt-1";
            ramdisk = "ramdisk-1";
            signature {
                algo = "sha256,rsa2048";
                key-name-hint = "dev";
                sign-images = "kernel", "fdt", "ramdisk";
            };
        };
    };
};
```

With my limited test, the only way `mkimage` command adds two keys into u-boot.dtb is the following setup. Essentially the second key just used as a backup option. This seems to corresponding to U-boot document. But this is not fit for my use case.
The document says

> - key-name-hint: Name of key used for signing. This is only a hint since it
>     is possible for the name to be changed. Verification can proceed by checking
>     all available signing keys until one matches.
>     "

```
/dts-v1/;
/ {
    description = "fitImage for Tegra TX2";
    #address-cells = <1>;
    images {
        kernel-1 {
            description = "Linux kernel";
            data = /incbin/("Image");
            ...
            hash-1 {
                algo = "sha256";
            };
        };
        fdt-1 {
            description = "DTB for Tegra TX2";
            data = /incbin/("tegra186-base.dtb");
            ...
            hash-1 {
                algo = "sha256";
            };
        };
        ramdisk-1 {
            description = "Ramdisk Image for Tegra TX2";
            data = /incbin/("initrd");
            ...
            hash-1 {
                algo = "sha256";
            };
        };
    };
    configurations {
        default = "conf-1";
        conf-1 {
            description = "Production build";
            kernel = "kernel-1";
            fdt = "fdt-1";
            ramdisk = "ramdisk-1";
            signature-1 {
                algo = "sha256,rsa2048";
                key-name-hint = "prod";
                sign-images = "kernel", "fdt", "ramdisk";
            };
            signature-2 {
                algo = "sha256,rsa2048";
                key-name-hint = "dev";
                sign-images = "kernel", "fdt", "ramdisk";
            };
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: Hi, Is it resolved ? Did you need need to modify u-boot code ? What's the usage of "key-name-hint" ? (from u-boot code it seems that nothing is done with it)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ubootpubkey](https://gitlab.com/rkraevskiy/ubootpubkey) to embed keys to your u-boot dts file at u-boot compilation time